# Triggers updating/inserting in 2 different databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, triggers

I've 2 databases in the same SQL Server and I've triggers in both that insert/update/delete data in the other database.
Considering only performance will be any advantage in converting the 2 databases in just 1?

Comment: If the triggers are directly accessing the other databases, then you've already got the worst of both worlds - if one DB is offline, the other is non-functional (for the tables with these triggers)

Comment: That's a good question. The performance of the queries themselves should be the same; only you could lose a little bit of overhead which is used for connecting to the other database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, but he asked only for the performance aspect.

Comment: If the trigger is called very often, and if the action within is rather small, then you could gain some performance. I would make a try and run the SQL Profiler a while to see the result.

Comment: On the logical level, what does these database have in common? why are there 2 in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many caveats by this design. I'm quite sure there is a good reason for you to do this that way.

You have some issues:

- if one db is offline, both db's won't work as expected.
- If you have different permissions you need to keep care of them
- it's not clear for every developer which changes has side-effects on other databases
- ...

On the performance side:

- it could maybe decrease performance as any action in db 1 needs to get an db lock (S) in db 2.
- if db 2 is exclusively (X) locked by any process your trigger will wait until db 2 will be released - this means your process in db 1 will hang there too.

Best regards,Ionic